# R cor returns NaN sometimes

Tags: r, nan, correlation

I've been working on some data, available here: [Dropbox' csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i0ou1rywjvkuwkq/120.csv?dl=0) (please be kind to use it to replicate the error).

When I run the code:

```
t<-read.csv("120.csv")
x<-NULL
for (i in 1:100){
  x<-c(x,cor(t$nitrate,t$sulfate,use="na.or.complete"))
}
sum(is.nan(x))
```

I get random values of the last expression, usually around 55 to 60. I expect `cor` to give repetible results, so I expect `x` to be a vector of length=100 made of identical values. See, for example, the output of two independent runs:

```
> x<-NULL; for (i in 1:100){x<-c(x,cor(t$nitrate,t$sulfate,use="na.or.complete"))}
> sum(is.nan(x))
[1] 62
> head(x,10)
 [1]       NaN       NaN 0.2967441       NaN 0.2967441       NaN       NaN       NaN
 [9] 0.2967441       NaN
> x<-NULL; for (i in 1:100){x<-c(x,cor(t$nitrate,t$sulfate,use="na.or.complete"))}
> sum(is.nan(x))
[1] 52
> head(x,10)
 [1] 0.2967441       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN 0.2967441 0.2967441       NaN
 [9] 0.2967441 0.2967441
>
```

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong here, or if it's a[n] [un]known bug. If that's the case, I appreciate if somebody more profficient than I helps me reporting it to CRAN.

I read a very old (2001) post where the same behavior was exhibited by cor.test (see [cor.test produces NaN sometimes](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/019ny8n653/r-cor-test-x-x-sometimes-produce-nan).

I appreciate your kind explanations, as I'm a nOOb to R. Thanks!

Per Ben's Suggestion:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Colombia.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Colombia.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Colombia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                     
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Colombia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stringr_0.6.2     digest_0.6.4      RCurl_1.95-4.3    bitops_1.0-6      qpcR_1.4-0        Matrix_1.1-4      robustbase_0.91-1 rgl_0.95.1157    
 [9] minpack.lm_1.1-8  MASS_7.3-35       plyr_1.8.1        swirl_2.2.16      ggplot2_1.0.0     lattice_0.20-29  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 DEoptimR_1.0-2   grid_3.1.1       gtable_0.1.2     httr_0.5         labeling_0.3     munsell_0.4.2    proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.3     
[10] reshape2_1.4     scales_0.2.4     testthat_0.9.1   tools_3.1.1      yaml_2.1.13
```

Results of find("cor"):

```
> find("cor")
[1] "package:stats"
```

---------- ### Second Edit ###--------

I restarted the session (I didn't quite find how to pass the --vanilla argument. I'm using Rstudio), and this is the new sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Colombia.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Colombia.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Colombia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                     
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Colombia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

I run the commands again in the new session, and still get sum(is.nan(x))=52 :(

Just in case it's useful:

```
> cor
function (x, y = NULL, use = "everything", method = c("pearson", 
    "kendall", "spearman")) 
{
    na.method <- pmatch(use, c("all.obs", "complete.obs", "pairwise.complete.obs", 
        "everything", "na.or.complete"))
    if (is.na(na.method)) 
        stop("invalid 'use' argument")
    method <- match.arg(method)
    if (is.data.frame(y)) 
        y <- as.matrix(y)
    if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        x <- as.matrix(x)
    if (!is.matrix(x) && is.null(y)) 
        stop("supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'")
    if (!(is.numeric(x) || is.logical(x))) 
        stop("'x' must be numeric")
    stopifnot(is.atomic(x))
    if (!is.null(y)) {
        if (!(is.numeric(y) || is.logical(y))) 
            stop("'y' must be numeric")
        stopifnot(is.atomic(y))
    }
    Rank <- function(u) {
        if (length(u) == 0L) 
            u
        else if (is.matrix(u)) {
            if (nrow(u) > 1L) 
                apply(u, 2L, rank, na.last = "keep")
            else row(u)
        }
        else rank(u, na.last = "keep")
    }
    if (method == "pearson") 
        .Call(C_cor, x, y, na.method, FALSE)
    else if (na.method %in% c(2L, 5L)) {
        if (is.null(y)) {
            .Call(C_cor, Rank(na.omit(x)), NULL, na.method, method == 
                "kendall")
        }
        else {
            nas <- attr(na.omit(cbind(x, y)), "na.action")
            dropNA <- function(x, nas) {
                if (length(nas)) {
                  if (is.matrix(x)) 
                    x[-nas, , drop = FALSE]
                  else x[-nas]
                }
                else x
            }
            .Call(C_cor, Rank(dropNA(x, nas)), Rank(dropNA(y, 
                nas)), na.method, method == "kendall")
        }
    }
    else if (na.method != 3L) {
        x <- Rank(x)
        if (!is.null(y)) 
            y <- Rank(y)
        .Call(C_cor, x, y, na.method, method == "kendall")
    }
    else {
        if (is.null(y)) {
            ncy <- ncx <- ncol(x)
            if (ncx == 0) 
                stop("'x' is empty")
            r <- matrix(0, nrow = ncx, ncol = ncy)
            for (i in seq_len(ncx)) {
                for (j in seq_len(i)) {
                  x2 <- x[, i]
                  y2 <- x[, j]
                  ok <- complete.cases(x2, y2)
                  x2 <- rank(x2[ok])
                  y2 <- rank(y2[ok])
                  r[i, j] <- if (any(ok)) 
                    .Call(C_cor, x2, y2, 1L, method == "kendall")
                  else NA
                }
            }
            r <- r + t(r) - diag(diag(r))
            rownames(r) <- colnames(x)
            colnames(r) <- colnames(x)
            r
        }
        else {
            if (length(x) == 0L || length(y) == 0L) 
                stop("both 'x' and 'y' must be non-empty")
            matrix_result <- is.matrix(x) || is.matrix(y)
            if (!is.matrix(x)) 
                x <- matrix(x, ncol = 1L)
            if (!is.matrix(y)) 
                y <- matrix(y, ncol = 1L)
            ncx <- ncol(x)
            ncy <- ncol(y)
            r <- matrix(0, nrow = ncx, ncol = ncy)
            for (i in seq_len(ncx)) {
                for (j in seq_len(ncy)) {
                  x2 <- x[, i]
                  y2 <- y[, j]
                  ok <- complete.cases(x2, y2)
                  x2 <- rank(x2[ok])
                  y2 <- rank(y2[ok])
                  r[i, j] <- if (any(ok)) 
                    .Call(C_cor, x2, y2, 1L, method == "kendall")
                  else NA
                }
            }
            rownames(r) <- colnames(x)
            colnames(r) <- colnames(y)
            if (matrix_result) 
                r
            else drop(r)
        }
    }
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000008ce0158>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: I appreciate if somebody could add the tag "cor". My reputation (still less than 1500) doesn't allow me to add new tags, and this one I think is critical for people facing the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW it looks like the old issue was fixed in R 1.4.0 (!): http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS.1 says `cor(*, use = "all.obs") <= 1 is now guaranteed which ensures that sqrt(1 - r^2) is always ok in cor.test(). (PR#1099)`

Comment: I can't replicate; I always get `sum(is.nan(x))` equal to zero.  (1) try starting in a clean R session (with `--vanilla` if possible); (2) results of `sessionInfo()`? (3) results of `find("cor")` ?

Comment: I suspect this is something wonky on your side, not a general bug, but it's a very well-asked question.

Comment: curiouser and curiouser.  My only remaining suggestion is a repetition of #1 above (make sure you're starting in a clean R session) -- appearance of non-recommended packages in your `sessionInfo()` output suggests you haven't done that yet.

Comment: bizarre. I hope someone can test this on 3.1.1 running on 64-bit Windows.  A bug seems very, very, very, unlikely, but I'm running out of alternative explanations.

Comment: @Ben: Is the code of your cor equal to the one I posted in the edit?

Comment: Yes, at a quick glance. (The bytecode is different, but I think I'd expect that on different platforms.)  I don't see anything about `cor.test` in the latest NEWS entries (esp. for 3.1.1 -> 3.1.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puzzled as I was, I started playing around with the various options on the `use=` argument of cor. I found that I can have consistent results if I use `cor(t$nitrate,t$sulfate,use="pairwise.complete.obs")`:

```
> x<-NULL; for (i in 1:100){x<-c(x,cor(t$nitrate,t$sulfate,use="pairwise.complete.obs"))};x
  [1] 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441
 [12] 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441
 [23] 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441
 [34] 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441
 [45] 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441
 [56] 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441
 [67] 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441
 [78] 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441
 [89] 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441 0.2967441
[100] 0.2967441
```

I still don't get why other options of `use` passed by other users didn't cause the weird behavior.

Comment: As @MartinMächler said, this is more of a workaround than a solution, but might help someone, so I'm marking it as an aswer.

Answer (score 6):

Several comments and notes:

- Nobody is able to reproduce your problem
- it cannot be a problem with the `120.csv` file which is all fine.
- Really, using another  `use=".."` option is just a workaround
- The underlying C code in R's sources uses  `ISNAN(.)` everywhere for detecting if a value is NA or NaN    and this in term goes to your (system internal) C library's `isnan(.)` function.
- you (and **only** you) sometimes get `NaN` because `ISNAN(.)` does not return "true" in some cases it should, and the floating point arithmetic computes with the NAs and correctly returns NaN's.

As an "old" R core member, I can assure you that  ISNAN(.) is used in many many fundamental places inside R's core computations, and the observations that **for you** it sometimes seems to not detect NA/NaN so that they propagate into the result is **very problematic**.
As Duncan Murdoch has said, answering your R bug report
https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16058
this must be a problem with your specific "system" one way or the other...
As I assume you simply downloaded R from CRAN, also for R 3.1.2, and you still see the problem,
I'd tend to say that your system software (Windows) or - less likely - your hardware must be slightly broken / corrupt.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was planning to link here to the discussion in the bug report, but you went ahead! Duncan suggested there could be a problem with the msvcrt.dll library or something wrong with the floating point processor. I read some similar complaints from octave builds, so that let me thinking (once again) to migrate to Linux or OSX. If this indeed is a library problem, though, I'm pretty sure some people is unaware of the problem going in their system out there. I hope somebody fixes that. In the meanwhile, as you suggested, I'll mark my own reply as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Giovanni, 
It its working fine for me. 
Maybe you should try to change the parameters of cor to use =  "complete.obs" and see if that helps. 
Also you should check your CSV file weather they are corrupted or not.

I hope it helps.

Comment: it would be helpful to post your R version and platform for this kind of answer.

Comment: @Danish: Thanks for your suggestion. It still produces inconsistent results. On the other hand, if the csv was corrupted, then it would produce **consistent** unexpected (or wrong) results. What really puzzles me is the inconsistency.