# Cumsum function result is different from iterative loop

Tags: r

I tried to replace for-loop addition with R function cumsum(), however the results are slightly different. The differences are mostly trivial. Still, I'm wondering what's causing the issue.

```
day <- c(1:100)
curve <- sapply(day, function(x){0.01 * exp(-(x/30.5)^0.7)})

methodA <- cumsum(curve)

methodB <- array(dim = length(day))
methodB[1] <- curve[1]
for (i in c(2: length(day))){
  methodB[i] <- methodB[i-1] + curve[i]
}

identical(methodA, methodB)
#### FALSE
mean(methodA - methodB) == 0
#### FALSE: ~ 4.37e-17
```

Comment: I think it's just floating point rounding error

Comment: You may prefer `all.equal()` for these comparisons which tests "near equality".

Comment: are you using windows? check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745943/r-cor-returns-nan-sometimes

Comment: Try initializing a vector not array and run the running sum version: `methodB <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(day)); for (i in c(1:length(day))) methodB[i] <- sum(curve[1:i])`